# Creating an "array_like" QImage subclass for numpy.array()

Tags: numpy, pyside, qimage

I want to **create an "`array_like`" `QImage` subclass that can be passed to `numpy.array()`**.
I'd like to avoid using `PIL` as a substitute; the whole point of this is to avoid the dependency on `PIL`.  Besides, constantly converting between `QImage` and the `PIL Image` is impractical for my program.

I find the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html) cryptic, and after reading it I'm still confused about how to emulate the array interface.  As the numpy documentation states, to qualify as an "`array_like`" object, it needs the `__array_interface__` attribute, which is a dictionary with five keys.  However, I've never dealt with types, buffers, and memory before; if someone could explain how to solve this problem it would be much appreciated.

I'm using Python 3.3 and PySide 1.1.2.
Thanks to all who reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to just use the buffer object returned from `QImage.bits()` and `np.frombuffer()`.

```
def qimage2array(q_image):
    width = q_image.width()
    height = q_image.height()
    arr = np.frombuffer(q_image.bits(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape([height, width, -1])
    return arr
```

Comment: How do you determine the appropriate `dtype`?  What's the relation between `QImage.format()` and the `dtype`?

Comment: I don't recommend using an image format for which `uint8` is not an appropriate dtype. numpy won't be able to do much with any of the other packed formats. Use `QImage.convertToFormat()` to convert the `QImage` to one of the RGB32 formats.

Comment: `np.frombuffer(img.bits(), dtype=np.uint32).reshape(img.height(), img.width())` with `qRgba`, `qRed` etc. worked best for me.